# How can I stop a jQuery loop animation?

Tags: jquery, animation, loops

I have an image which is rotated 90 degress right and left continuously and I'm trying to stop it but I can't figure out how.

I tried to put the function in an `If` statement so I can call `function = false;` or `true` but it doesn't work.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gpPcU/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the callback function to false

```
$("img").rotate({angle:0, callback:function(){ false; }});
```

Comment: This will do it too. I like this answer more than mine.

Comment: @maxedison Yep, same do I. Thanks alot both

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JQuery stop method( http://api.jquery.com/stop/ )

Ex:

```
$('.img').stop(true, true)
```

Comment: -1: This doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/gpPcU/15/  The reason it doesn't work is because .stop() stops currently running & queued animation. But if you look at his code, you'll see that the callback functions essentially generate a loop that constantly queues new animations. So .stop() will stop the current ones, but then new animations get queued immediately afterwards. The key is to break the callback loop, as I do in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it: http://jsfiddle.net/gpPcU/3/

I'm not sure what you tried with the If statement you mentioned because that's not in your fiddle, but you were probably on the right track. Here are the main changes I made:

`rotate()` callback within `test()`:

```
    function(){
        if(!$('img').hasClass('stop')){
            rotation()
         }else{
             $('img').rotate({angle:0});
         }
    }
```

Button click event:

```
$(".btn").click(function(){
    $("img").addClass('stop');
});
```